# OpenCV linux make windows borderless and without title

Tags: python, linux, opencv

what I am trying to achieve is the cv window without borders and title.

What I have so far is this:

```
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    self.WINDOW_NAME = 'Camera'
    self.CV_SYSTEM_CACHE_CNT = 5 # Cv has 5-frame cache
    self.LOOP_INTERVAL_TIME = 0.2

    cv.NamedWindow(self.WINDOW_NAME, cv.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)
    self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

    root = tk.Tk()

    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    cv2.resizeWindow(self.WINDOW_NAME, 320, 240)
    cv2.moveWindow(self.WINDOW_NAME, screen_width/2 - 160, screen_height/2 - 120 + int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Is it possible?

if not, is there some workaround in linux which I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: Use a GUI toolkit. OpenCV just provides few limited UI functions for convenient prototyping.

Comment: Maybe if you build openCV with the Qt Gui ? THere are a few more window options, then : http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedwindow